# Facing issue while loading app to PCF

Tags: pcf

Bean method 'configServicePropertySource' in 'ConfigServiceBootstrapConfiguration' not loaded because @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.cloud.config.enabled) found different value in property 'spring.cloud.config.enabled'
   2017-12-17T14:40:46.20+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT Field locator in io.pivotal.spring.cloud.service.config.ConfigClientOAuth2BootstrapConfiguration$ConfigClientOAuth2Configurer required a bean of type 'org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator' that could not be found.

-I am receiving the above message when I am trying to load it into PCF.  But when running locally, it is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

When this error message appeared in a Spring Boot 2.01 / Pivotal Cloud Foundry / Groovy / Gradle environment, one additional thing I noticed was that the problem went away when I removed the dependency on the Spring Boot based module that was being developed.

The fix was to change the build.gradle of the imported module so that dependencies were compileOnly() instead of compile().

Like this,

```
    compileOnly('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter')
    compileOnly('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-amqp')
    compileOnly('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-config-server')
    compileOnly('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-amqp')
    testCompile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-config-server')
```

Instead of,

```
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-amqp')
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-config-server')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor')
```

My theory is that there was a conflict between multiple instances of the Spring Boot framework in the environment and this removed one of them, but I'm not certain if that is correct.

Here is the complete error message from my environment:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
Description:
Parameter 1 of constructor in io.pivotal.spring.cloud.service.config.ConfigClientOAuth2BootstrapConfiguration$ConfigClientOAuth2Configurer required a bean of type 'org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator' that could not be found.
- Bean method 'configServicePropertySource' in 'ConfigServiceBootstrapConfiguration' not loaded because @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.cloud.config.enabled) found different value in property 'spring.cloud.config.enabled'
Action:
Consider revisiting the conditions above or defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator' in your configuration.
```

While troubleshooting different combinations of Spring Boot modules I also saw this error, which I believe had the same cause:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
Description:
Parameter 0 of constructor in io.pivotal.spring.cloud.service.config.VaultTokenRenewalAutoConfiguration required a bean of type 'io.pivotal.spring.cloud.service.config.ConfigClientOAuth2ResourceDetails' that could not be found.
[OUT] Action:
[OUT] Consider defining a bean of type 'io.pivotal.spring.cloud.service.config.ConfigClientOAuth2ResourceDetails' in your configuration.
```

Comment: Note: this application worked fine locally with the compile() configuration - it was only after loading to PCF that this problem appeared, probably because of the additional security elements.